# Deleting entry in input

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
$('#enterTags').keydown(function(event) {
    var tag = $(this).val();
    // 188 is comma, 13 is enter
    if (event.which === 188 || event.which === 13) {
        if (tag) {
            $('#falseInput').val($('#falseInput').val() + tag + ', ');
            $(this).val('');
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    // 8 is backspace
    else if (event.which == 8) {
        if (!tag) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

The problem I am having now is when a user presses backspace, I need it to clear #falseInput of the most recent "tag" var I entered in #enterTags.  How can I do this?

Comment: So are you trying to go back to the original value of `$('#falseInput') before you added `tag` to it, or are you trying to just make `$('#falseInput').val()` empty again?

Comment: I'm trying to go back to the original value of #falseInput before I added the last tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the tags in an array and set the value of `#falseInput` by joining the elements of the array ([`join` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)). Then, when the user presses backspace, just remove the last element of the array. This approach will be easier than trying to manipulate the string stored in the input.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, sorry.

Comment: I suggest that you read up on some jQuery tutorials and JavaScript in general then. This site isn't really meant for you to post your problem and have other people write your code for you. Give this solution a try, and if you get stuck with a specific problem, post another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep each completed tag in a stack by doing `tagsArray.push(tag);`. You can display the array by doing `$('#falseInput').val(tagsArray.join(', '));`

When the backspace is pressed, all you need to do is

```
tagsArray.pop();
$('#falseInput').val(tagsArray.join(', '));
```

That removes the most recent value from the array then redoes the value of `#falseInput`

Comment: So if(tag), I push tag into the array and display it.
And on backspace, I pop the tag?